# How should I pass assigned variables to an included Jekyll file?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I use github pages to host a jekyll website. In order to quickly switch beetween the online base URL and the locale base URL, I have a variable in the start of my default layout file:

```
<!--{% assign root = site.github.url %}-->
{% assign root = "." %}
```

However, if I try to use that variable in an included file, it doesn't work. I know it should be refered as `{{ include.root }}` and I tried several variations so far, but none worked:

```
  {% include rail.html root =  root %}
  {% include rail.html root =  page.root %}
  {% include rail.html root =  {{ root }} %}
```

Any idea of what I should do?

Note that I am calling the include from an index file using the `default.html` file as layout. I can print the `root` variable correctly in that index file.

Also, how can I share a parent data context without having to pass all the parameters to my included file?

---

edit: it looks like I got something wrong. I tried to put inline posts into an include and the data context is perfectly shared. No idea why it doesn't work with my root variable only in the includes

Comment: Any repository url to share ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Sure, here it is: https://github.com/Remosco/website. The website is live on the related url (https://remosco.github.io/website). Since you seem to know your way around with Jekyll, feel free to tell me what you think about it. First time using Jekyll in an actual work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include tag has the following syntax: `{% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %}`

- `{% include rail.html root =  page.root %}` does not work because `root` is not defined as an attribute of `page`.
- `{% include rail.html root =  {{ root }} %}` has wrong syntax, **you must remove the whole line from the source code**, or it will make the `build` fail.
- First one is correct: `{% include rail.html root =  root %}`
  Then in `_includes/rail.html` : `{{ include.root }}` should print the `root` value, if that does not work the error is in another place, not in the include.

## Side note

If you define the variable before the include, then you can use it directly without `include.`:

```
{% assign root = "." %}
{% include rail.html %}
```

In `_includes/rail.html`:

```
Hello {{root}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I will try it first thing tomorrow and validate the answer asap. What you describe as the correct way to do it is the first one I tried. However, while it works everywhere else, it doesn't with this `root` variable. I will double check things and come back with news. Thanks again :)

Comment: Important side note.

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work. Could it be because I define `root` in the default layout, pass it through its `content` to a page which will load the include? After several checks, it works in none of my includes.

Comment: I don't understand it well, can you update the question including that code?